# Distribution of $\langle x^2,a\rangle$ where $x$ is is a random direction?

Tags: normal-distribution, circular-statistics

Suppose $x\in R^n$ follows the uniform distribution on the surface of a unit sphere centered at 0 and $a$ is a vector in $R^n$. What can we say about the distribution of the following quantity?

$$\sum_i x_i^2 a_i $$

Mean seems to be $\frac{\sum_i a_i}{n}$, what about the variance?

This quantity is the value of quadratic form with eigenvalues $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ when evaluated at some point on the surface of unit sphere.

[image]
[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-dirichlet.nb)

Comment: So are you only asking about the variance of $\sum_i x_i^2 a_i$? Also, what exactly do you mean by "sample from Gaussian, normalize"?

Comment: I mean that it's a uniform distribution on a sphere, I've edited with a more precise definition from Mardia

Comment: Is $\langle x^2,a\rangle$ geometrically meaningful? Or where and how does it arise?

Comment: @MattF. it's the value of $x'Ax$ where $A$ is a diagonal matrix with $a_i$ as diagonal entries

Comment: The variance is $$\frac{2}{n^2(n+2)}\sum_{i<j}(a_i-a_j)^2$$ and the mean, as you said, is $\frac{1}{n}\sum a_i$. I may write up a proof tomorrow if no one gives a reference first.

Comment: Looks interesting! Proof/reference would be great. Another interpretation, it's the average value on unit circle for quadratic centered at 0 and Hessian A

Comment: Just to be clear, we are talking about a uniform random point on the *surface* of a sphere (as opposed to the interior of the ball), right?

Comment: @Ben, yes, as you can see from the stated mean. Eg in the case $n=2$, $a=(1,0)$, the expectation on the (edge of the) circle is $\int (\cos \theta)^2 d\theta/(2\pi)=1/2$, agreeing with the expression given, while the expectation over the interior is $\iint (r \cos \theta)^2 r \, dr \, d\theta/\pi=1/4$.

Comment: A multiple of $(x_1^2,x_2^2\ldots,x_p^2)$ has a Dirichlet$(1/2,1/2,\ldots,1/2)$ distribution when the sphere is centered at the origin (as strongly implied by your quotation).  That will lend itself to further analysis.  It yields the moments easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with $m(a)=E[\langle x^2,a\rangle]$ and $s(a)=E[\langle x^2,a\rangle^2]$, so that the variance will be $s(a)-m(a)^2$.

We will calculate these by expressing $x$ in $n$-dimensional [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates), so
\begin{align}
& & x_1&=\cos(\phi_1)\\
0\ \le\ &\phi_1\le\pi & x_2&=\sin(\phi_1)\cos(\phi_2)\\
0\ \le\ &\phi_2\le\pi & x_3&=\sin(\phi_1)\sin(\phi_2)\cos(\phi_3)\\
&\vdots & \vdots\\
0\ \le\ & \phi_{n-1}\le\pi & x_{n-1}&=\sin(\phi_1)\cdots\sin(\phi_{n-2})\cos(\phi_{n-1})\\
0\ \le\ &\phi_n\le2\pi & x_n&=\sin(\phi_1)\cdots\sin(\phi_{n-2})\sin(\phi_{n-1})\\
\end{align}
and the element of $n-1$-dimensional surface area is
$$dS = \sin^{n-2}(\phi_1)\sin^{n-3}(\phi_2)\cdots \sin(\phi_{n-2})\ d\phi_1\, d\phi_2 \cdots d\phi_n$$

We begin with some special cases, letting
$b_i$ be the vector that agrees with $a$ on the $i^{th}$ coordinate and is zero elsewhere. First,
\begin{align}
m(b_1)&=\frac
{\int\cdots\int a_1\cos^2(\phi_1)\, dS}
{\int\cdots\int dS}\\
&=\frac{\int a_1\cos^2(\phi_1)\sin^{n-2}(\phi_1)\,d\phi_1}{\int \sin^{n-2}(\phi_1)\,d\phi_1}\\
&=a_1\left(1-\frac{\int \sin^n(\phi_1)\,d\phi_1}
{\int \sin^{n-2}(\phi_1)\,d\phi_1}\right)\\
&=a_1\left(1-\frac{n-1}{n}\right)\\
&=a_1/n
\end{align}
where the integrals over higher $\phi_i$ cancel, and the final [ratio](https://www.stumblingrobot.com/2015/10/21/use-integration-by-parts-to-find-a-formula-for-the-integral-of-sinn/) uses integration by parts.
Since $m$ must be symmetric in all the coordinates, we get
\begin{align}
m(b_i)&=b_i/n\\
m(a)=m\left(\sum b_i\right)&=\sum m(b_i)=\frac{1}{n}\sum a_i
\end{align}
Similarly,
\begin{align}
s(b_i)&=3a_i^2/(n^2+2n)\\
s(b_i+b_j)-s(b_i)-s(b_j)&=2a_ia_j/(n^2+2n)
\end{align}

Now by the polynomial identity
$$\left(\sum x_i\right)^2=\sum_i x_i^2+\sum_{i<j} \left((x_i+x_j)^2 - x_i^2-x_j^2\right)$$
we also have
\begin{align}
s(a)
&=s\left(\sum b_i\right)\\
&=\sum_i s(b_i)+\sum_{i<j}\left(s(b_i+b_j)-s(b_i)-s(b_j)\right)\\
&=\sum_i \frac{3a_i^2}{n^2+2n}+\sum_{i<j}\frac{2a_ia_j}{n^2+2n}
\end{align}

So finally, the variance is
\begin{align}
v&=s(a)-m(a)^2\\
&=\sum_{i}a_i^2\left(\frac{3}{n^2+2n}-\frac{1}{n^2}\right) + \sum_{i<j} a_ia_j\left(\frac{2}{n^2+2n}-\frac{2}{n^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{2}{n^2(n+2)}\left((n-1)\sum_{i}a_i^2 - 2\sum_{i<j} a_ia_j\right)\\
&=\frac{2}{n^2(n+2)}\sum_{i<j}(a_i-a_j)^2
\end{align}

Comment: +1. Re the expectations: because the $x_i$ are exchangeable, all the $x_i^2$ have the same expectation.  Since these $n$ squares sum to unity, that common expectation must be $1/n.$  Re the covariances: the covariance matrix of $(x_i^2)$ is readily obtained from the marginal distribution derived at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/520811/919. Some people might find these approaches more congenial than resorting to spherical coordinates.

Comment: that looks intense....but matches what I'm getting numerically, thanks!

Comment: @whuber, that is slicker! I am just happy that these calculations turned out nicer than most with high-dimensional spherical coordinates: no multiple integrals, no gamma function, and no alternating appearances of $\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: Indeed.  But it is a little sobering to look at the full distribution for various vectors $(a_i)$ ;-).