# What is the value of $\sum_i x_i^2 v_i$ for isotropic $x$?

Tags: normal-distribution, circular-statistics

Suppose $x$ is an isotropic random variable in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with $E[\|x\|^2]=d$ and $v$ is some vector. It appears that $\sum_i x_i^2 v_i \approx \sum_i v_i$ when $d \approx \infty$.

What is an easy way of showing it?

The hard way is to follow this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/532222/511) or this [paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.46.4629&rep=rep1&type=pdf&ref=machine-learning-etc.ghost.io).

Comment: How does the "IE" follow?  I think that's not true.

Comment: By "IE", I mean that in $\sum_i x_i^2 v_i$, we can replace random $x_i^2$ with 1's, without changing the result much

Comment: But the "well approximated" statement appears to be incorrect.

Comment: @whuber how about this -- for any linear function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ we have $d\approx \infty \implies f(x_1^2,\ldots,x_d^2)\approx f(1, 1, \ldots, 1)$

Comment: Wondering if there's a version of Weak Law of Large Numbers which could apply when there's some constraint on uniformity of $v_i$'s