# Is this rato between sum of squares beta distributed?

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, beta-distribution

Consider $x_i \sim N(\mu,\sigma)$ I am interested in distribution of the the following statistic (arises from likelyhood ratio test):
$$
\frac{
\sum_{n=1}^{n} (x_i - \overline{x})^2
}{
\sum_{n=1}^{n} (x_i - \mu)^2
}
$$

where $\overline{x}$ is the sample mean

After observing distribution of this statistic with simulation for couple of N I noticed that it looks awfully like $Beta(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{n-2}{2},\frac{1}{2})$

Here are how empirical and beta CDF look like when plotted against each other for n=2,3 and 10:

[image: n=2]

[image: n=3]

[image: n=10]

Is my guess correct?

Comment: This result is stated (in terms of Gamma distributions) in the Wikipedia article on Beta distributions at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Derived_from_other_distributions.  Note the typographic error in your question, though: Beta distributions have *positive* parameters, not negative ones.  Closely related posts here on CV include https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/520498

Comment: Fixed the typo, thanks. Yes, the conclusion can be derived from the wiki page. If you post this as an answer I can accept it.